# Which 품사 is 대신? Is it always 명사?

Tags: grammar

Naver defines 대명사 as

> 사람이나 사물의 이름을 대신 나타내는 말.

What role does 대신 play in the above sentence? According to the dictionary it is always a noun. I need your help to understand the sentence structure.

Comment: A somewhat connected question that may be of interest: http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/285/are-all-words-from-chinese-characters-%ED%95%9C%EC%9E%90%EC%96%B4-nouns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topo morto's example shows the basic form:

> 그 대신 제가 가겠습니다.  (I will go instead of [as a substitute for] him.)

Notice:

1. 대신 is, or works like, an adverb (as other answers have said).
2. 대신 takes an object, i.e. 그.  ("Object" may not be a term of formal grammar.)

On item 1, consider:

> - The **time** we were in Spain, I didn't know you that well.
> - The **work** of his life done, he retired.

They can become

> - **At** the time we were in Spain, . . .
> - **With** the work of his life done, . . .

Similarly we can fill things in:

> 그**를** 대신**하여** 제가 가겠습니다.

Note:  I am not suggesting that the three examples have the same grammatical analysis.  Just illustrating how *what looks like a noun* can *work like something else*, to make the idea more palatable.

On item 2, if you have a transitive verb in place of 가겠습니다, you may get something like:

> 그를 대신하여 제가 일을 하겠습니다.  (Instead of him, I will do the work.)

As for your phrase:

> 사람이나 사물의 이름을 대신 나타내는 말

Converting it to:

> 대명사는 사람이나 사물의 이름을 대신(하여) 나타낸다.

you can see that it is ambiguous.

One possibility is that 나타낸다 has an object, but 대신하여 does not.  I.e., the sentence means:

> A pronoun, as a substitute (*of what?*), represents the name of a person or thing.

The second possibility is the opposite.  대신하여 has an object.  나타낸다 does not.

> A pronoun, as a substitute of the name of a person or thing, represents (*what?*).

The full sentence may go:

> 대명사는 사람이나 사물의 이름을 대신(하여) 그 사람이나 사물을 나타낸다.
>   (A pronoun, as a substitute for the name of a person or thing, represents that person or thing.)

The original, ambiguous phrase is somewhat sloppy.  That may have given you trouble in addition to 대신, supposedly a noun, working like something else.

You may also dispute the idea that a pronoun acts as a substitute for any name.  If you say:

> I met a blind beggar, and he said I should be king.

You don't care what his name was, and *he* is not a substitute for any name.  But this is not a Korean language question.

Answer (score 3):

연상 부사 is a conjuctive adverb. It's poses as an adverb but acts to combine two phrases/words.

I should point out, you can supplant the word 'instead' in most cases including this one.

I learned the idiom 꿩대신닭 which means to expect something good but not get it. 'chicken instead of quail'.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more by providing some examples and references?

Comment: I've had 꿩대신닭 my whole life, I think!

Answer (score 2):

[**As naver dictionary says**](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=b234494ceb344e3aaa3a31a4ad2f76b8), it can be a 명사 (noun), in which case it means something like a 'stand-in' or 'substitute'. More commonly, it's a 부사 (adverb) meaning 'instead', 'instead of', 'in the place of':

> 대신 홍차를 주세요 - Give me tea instead.
>
> 그 대신 제가 가겠습니다 - I will go in his place.

Having said that, your definition for '대명사' (pronoun) is slightly difficult to translate word for word in English without introducing a tautology, because 나타내는 has a similar meaning of 'representing' or 'representative'. Perhaps you could say "A representative word used instead of the name of a person or thing".